# cx_Oracle and context lib is this correct

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I am curious to know if this is the correct way of using cx_Oracle with context lib and connection pooling using DBRCP.

```
import cx_Oracle
import threading
import time

def get_connection():
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user='username', password='password', dsn='mydsn_name/service_name:pooled')
return connection   

def myfunc(): 
    with get_connection() as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        for _ in range(10):
            cursor.execute("select * from mytable")
            val = cursor.fetchone()
            time.sleep(60)
            print("Thread", threading.current_thread().name, "fetched sequence =", val)

results = []
for thread in range(0,10):
    current_thread = threading.Thread(name = f'Thread {thread}', target = myfunc)
    results.append(current_thread)
    current_thread.start()


print('Started All Threads')

for thread in results:
    thread.join()

print("All done!")
```

I am not sure If i am doing the right thing here .

And have no idea how to confirm that the connection is being returned to the **connection pool**.

And each thread is not opening a **brand new connection** to the database.

Although the doc's on cx_Oracle seem to indicate i am on the right path.

Comment: Did you receive an error? Try printing the table names in the database. If you see names, you have established a connection.

Comment: No error works like magic let me update my doubts and be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get most benefit if you also use a cx_Oracle connect pool at the same time as DRCP.  You need to set `cclass` with DRCP otherwise you will lose its benefits. You can then decide what level of session reuse (the 'purity') to use.  Check the cx_Oracle [tutorial](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/tutorial/Python-and-Oracle-Database-12c-Scripting-for-the-Future.html). From [solutions/connect_pool2.py](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/tutorial/solutions/connect_pool2.py):

```
pool = cx_Oracle.SessionPool("pythonhol", "welcome", "localhost/orclpdb:pooled",
                             min = 2, max = 5, increment = 1, threaded = True)

def Query():
    con = pool.acquire(cclass="PYTHONHOL", purity=cx_Oracle.ATTR_PURITY_SELF)
    #con = pool.acquire(cclass="PYTHONHOL", purity=cx_Oracle.ATTR_PURITY_NEW)
    cur = con.cursor()
    for i in range(4):
        cur.execute("select myseq.nextval from dual")
        seqval, = cur.fetchone()
```

There are V$ views like V$CPOOL_STATS you can query to check whether DRCP is being used.  Links to some resources are in https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#drcp

Comment: Thanks Chris can you please show me an example of using the with clause to do what you have shown

Comment: Also chris when i use the database resident connection pooling instead of session pool my workload completes in half the time so not sure why the tutorial recommends the approach of using the sessionPool i find connection pool far superior